# how to handle 405 error for displaying as webpage laravel

Tags: php, laravel, rest

Im testing my laravel rest API with postman, my end point only allow POST method but when i test it with GET method the body return webpage instead of json. How could i handle the response to return json although the response is 405?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can handle it in function `render` of `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`

Ex:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
   if ($e instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException) {
      return response()->json(['message' => $e->getMessage(), 405);
   }
   return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

The docs for it: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/errors#render-method

I think Laravel has the response as JSON for it by default. You also can add to headers of request.

```
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
```

Comment: $e->getMessage() return empty string

Comment: You can use your custom message.
`return response()->json(['message' => 'Method is not allowed!', 405);`